# I wrote this command, and it works, but the completions buffer takes a couple seconds to display. Why?

Tags: key-bindings, completion

Using the helper command `last-message` from [another StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154098/copy-the-last-emacs-message-into-the-current-buffer), I wrote and bound an anonymous function to switch to the completion buffer if it exists, and if it doesn't exist but would be created by `TAB TAB`, create that buffer. The function works as intended, except for one problem... It's really slow at displaying the new buffer when it's created. I was first running it in a Python inferior shell for testing, but it has the same behavior in `M-x shell`.

The function appears to be as fast as you'd expect (basically instant). If I press `C-TAB` and hit the down arrow, I immediately see the buffer. However, if I press `C-TAB` and do nothing, it takes 2-3 seconds for the window to pop up.

```
(defun last-message (&optional num)
  (or num (setq num 1))
  (if (= num 0)
      (current-message)
    (save-excursion
      (set-buffer "*Messages*")
      (save-excursion
        (forward-line (- 1 num))
        (backward-char)
        (let ((end (point)))
          (forward-line 0)
          (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) end))))))

(global-set-key [C-tab]
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (switch-to-completions)
                  (if (string= "No completions" (last-message))
                      (progn (completion-help-at-point)
                             (switch-to-completions)))))
```

Comment: Why the nested `save-excursion`s? (They only became noticeable after fixing your unhelpful indentation, BTW.)

Comment: I didn't write that function, so I don't know. I copy-pasted it from another StackExchange question, which is linked in the question.

Comment: Perhaps the source code contained TAB chars. That can throw off indentation when it is pasted.

Comment: If you're NOT calling the command from within the minibuffer, `switch-to-completions` probably makes no sense and will build completions from the current buffer-string, which may explain the delay.

Comment: The intention is to build completions from the current buffer-string, if I understand your meaning. For example, I can use this function in an inferior Python shell.

Answer (score 1):

Scanning a command's messages is not a good way to determine its
result.  Maybe this is what you want.

```el
(defun completion-help-at-point-switch ()
  (interactive)
  (completion-help-at-point)
  (when completion-in-region-mode
    (switch-to-completions)))

(global-set-key [C-tab] #'completion-help-at-point-switch)
```